# change to other tab with setOnItemClickListener()

Tags: android, tabs

I have 3 tabs in my TabHost like you can see

```
  TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Comunidade");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("Comunidade");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("Notícias");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("Notícias");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("Web");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("Web");
    th.addTab(specs);
```

When the application starts the initial tab is **"Comunidade"** with a listView, so what i want is when i click on a item's list the View goes to the tab **"Web"** .

Here is the method :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

   ourweb.loadUrl(listadesites.get(pos).getEndereço());
   //CODE THAT I NEED
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TabHost.setCurrentTab, like this:

```
    TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    th.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with this code the app has stopped unexpectedly.


**EDIT**:
Ok the problem was that the tabhost must be declared like instance variable.

Comment: It shouldn't as long as you have at least 3 tabs added to the TabHost. Care for the exception log?

Comment: I didn't had declared TabHost as instance variable, and i put this in the //CODE THAT I NEED

   `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ourweb.loadUrl(listadesites.get(pos).getEndereço());
        th.setCurrentTabByTag("Web");`